# Refresh/Reload google maps API v2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-maps-v2

In my android application, I'm using Google Maps API v2 and navigation drawer to access various categories like culture, gastronomy,...

By default, the map loading all items but if I select a category, I would like the map is upgraded.

I've tried to call a method of fragment from my mainactivity but I create the fragment dinamically and I cant access to the "findFragmentById". This is my code:

**MapaFragment.java (Map fragment)**

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (container != null) {
            container.removeAllViews();
        }

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mapa, container, false);
        listaLugares = ((ListaLugares)getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        // obtengo el mapa       
        mapa = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        // Move the camera instantly to my position with a zoom of 15.
        LatLng miPosicion = new LatLng(main.obtLatitud, main.obtLongitud);
        mapa.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(miPosicion , 14) );

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        mapa.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14), 2000, null);

        // Add marker to the map
        addItemsToMap();


        return rootView;

    }

    public void addItemsToMap() {
        mapa.clear();
        if (listaLugares.lista.isEmpty()) {
            listaLugares.readPlaces(5000, 0, listaLugares.idCategoria);
        }

        LatLng miPosicion = new LatLng(main.obtLatitud, main.obtLongitud);
        mapa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(miPosicion)
            .title("Mi posición")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.location_icon)));

        for (int i = 0; i < listaLugares.lista.size(); i++) {

            LatLng posItem = new LatLng(listaLugares.lista.get(i).latitud,listaLugares.lista.get(i).longitud);

            mapa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(posItem)
                .title(listaLugares.lista.get(i).nombre)
                .snippet(listaLugares.lista.get(i).descripcion)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
            Log.v("MAPA", "Marker " + i + ": " + listaLugares.lista.get(i).nombre);
        }
    }
```

**fragment_mapa.xml (layout of fragment that contain a map)**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Note:** In **MainActivity.java**, I create the navigation drawer and when I select an item, it should refresh the map.

Comment: If you want to hide/show stuff without reloading the whole map (you will want that, eventually), have a reference to Marker/Polygon/Polyline (not MarkerOptions, etc), and use `setVisible` to toggle false/true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `addItemsToMap()` method with a different signature to pass the selected position of your drawer as a parameter of that method. So you will have :

```
public void addItemsToMap(int position) {
    switch(position) {
            case 0 : // show all

                    break;
            case 1 : // show markers of menu 1

                    break;
            case 2 : // show markers of menu 2

                    break;
            /* etc ... */
    }        
}
```

Now on your `onCreateView()` method, call `addItemsToMap(0)` to show all yours markers at

Comment: Thank you so much!! Your answer has been very useful. I needed only to pass the parameter map to the MainActivity but I created a global parameter 'map' and I solved it.